# Open universal link in app programmatically from browser

Tags: ios, safari, ios-universal-links

Is is possible to open a mobile app on iOS via a universal link programmatically or is this only possible via a user click?

I'm guessing this may not be allowed for security reasons.

**Process:**

1. The user has the app "myapp" installed. I have a button/url in an
   email that the user receives.
2. The user clicks the button/url which takes them to a webpage
   https://action.mypage.app. (The webpage url is actually wrapped in a
   sendgrid url).
3. At https://action.mypage.app an Angular application logs the action the
   user has taken and then opens another url which is a universal link
   that will open in "myapp" e.g. https://open.myapp.app

**Outcome:**
There are several outcomes on my test devices.

1. Rather than the mobile app being opened the equivalent web page https://open.myapp.app is opened in the mobile browser.
   This has the banner at the top "Open in the myapp app" with the apps icon.
2. Same as one but do not get the banner at all.
3. Note that for some iOS devices I use rather than opening in the browser it pops up a message "Open this page in "myapp"?" Cancel Open.
   If I click open it opens in the app if I click cancel it opens in the browser as above.

**Desired outcome:**

The mobile app is opened rather than the web page.

**Using a "user click":**

It works fine if I have a webpage that has a button that opens the url https://open.myapp.app.
This will open the mobile app no problems when the user clicks the button.

**Other:**
I did note this [article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/allowing-apps-and-websites-to-link-to-your-content) however the sub domain is not the same. The webpage is at https://action.mypage.app and the universal url is https://open.myapp.app:

> When a user browses your website in Safari and taps a universal link
> in the same domain, the system opens that link in Safari, respecting
> the user’s most likely intent to continue within the browser. If the
> user taps a universal link in a different domain, the system opens the
> link in your app.

**Update:**

I currently have this working by having a direct link from the email button/url to https://open.myapp.app and this opens in the app as expected.
I have removed the Sendgrid tracking and any custom action logging I am doing. I guess if I want to log the action I will need to do that from the mobile app when it opens.

Comment: `window.open` will iterate the handlers registered in the OS, at least for Chrome

Comment: I am facing exactly the same problem. I already have a middle page website, which will redirect the user to my registered universal link (the website and the universal link have different domain). I tried window.location, href,.. but the browser is just reload the content of my universal link instead of giving it the the OS. 
If you or some have solution, please advise.

Comment: No solution. Just the workaround I mention in the update.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has limited Universal Links in certain situations:

- Universal Links will not work if you paste the link into the browser
  URL field.
- Universal Links will not work with a user-driven  element click on the same domain. For example, if there
  is a Universal Link on google.com pointing to a different Universal
  Link on google.com, it will not open the app.
- Universal Links cannot
  be triggered via Javascript (in window.onload or via a .click() call
  on an  element) unless it is part of a user action.

> https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/ios-universal-links#appsbrowsers-that-support-universal-links

What I suppose to do is to add an **extra domain** to host the buttons, and use `window.location.href` instead of `a href`